# What is CDF $F_X(x) $ and $F_Y(y)$?

Tags: probability

I want to know how to find $F_X(x)$ , $F_Y(y)$ and $P(Y=1)$ given the following.

For the random variable $X$:

$f_X(x)= 1-\frac{x}{2}$ for $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $0$ otherwise

Random variable $Y = g(X)$ with

$g(x) = x$ for $x\leq 1$ and $1$ for $x>1$

Can someone please show me how to solve this ?

EDIT: $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}1-\frac{s}{2}ds=(x-\frac{x^2}{4})-(0-\frac{0}{4})$ where I used the fact that the lower boundary is $0$ and not infinity. Is this one correct? The other two are way more difficult to find I would say, I would appreciate it if someone can show it to me.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(s) ds$$
and
$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}[Y \le y] = \mathbb{P}[g(X) \le y]
$$
which you can further simplify using definition of $g$.

Comment: ... and $P(Y=1)=P(Y\leq 1) - P(Y<1)$....

Comment: @Math-fun thank you very much, appreciate it, totally overlooked

Comment: you are most welcome :-)

Comment: It would help me a lot more if I see it once how it's done... but thanks for the hint.